# How to switch between two applications without X environment

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux

On an embedded device, two GUI applications display the screen by directly writing /dev/fb0. One of them is a third party and the other is our own. Whether there is a way to write an application and freely switch between the two applications so that one of them is displayed on the actual screen.

Comment: You'd essentially be writing your own window system.

Comment: Can you modify and re-build the third-party application or is it provided as-is?

Comment: Do the switch at framebuffer driver's level, through either a custom framebuffer driver that will do the switch, or through a symlink?